# Dismiss view controller from @selector without creating seperate method

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm trying to dismiss the presented view controller by doing it from the button directly, instead of making a seperate method just for it, but I'm lost on how to get this to work, or if it's even possible.

Any help offered is appreciated!

Code I'm trying:

```
[dismissButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

What I'm NOT wanting to do:

```
- (void)dismissThis
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use the latter method? You can't pass custom data through `addTarget:...`

Comment: Only reason why is because I'm trying to have the fewest lines of code, and to see if it's even possible.

Comment: there's really no benefit to having fewer lines of code...

Comment: Sure there is, it's cleaner (to me) and less scrolling needed in Xcode

Comment: Yes, check out [JTTargetActionBlock](https://github.com/ZeR0-Wu/JTTargetActionBlock). Haven't used it in awhile, but has worked great for me in the past. Available as a Cocoapod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work like that. From the documentation of `UIControl`s `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`:

> The action message may optionally include the sender and the event as parameters, in that order.

So you have three possible selectors:

```
@selector(name)
@selector(nameWithParam:)
@selector(nameWithParam: otherParam:)
```

if your selector is `@selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)` it will be called with the sender instead of the animated BOOL and the event instead of the completion handler block which will crash you app.

edit to clarify why it crashes:
`dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` copies the completion block by sending the `copy` message. The event object doesn't implement `copy` and you will get an `NSInvalidArgumentException`.

Comment: Edit: it crashes when I try `@selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITouchesEvent copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9614d40'

Comment: What I meant to say is, you can't do it. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I can do it using the deprecated dismissModalViewController method, but I won't resort to doing that by any means. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Apple's standard API doesn't support it, but it's easy to add this functionality through a category on UIControl. [JTTargetActionBlock](https://github.com/ZeR0-Wu/JTTargetActionBlock) adds this functionality. It's also available [as a Cocoapod](http://cocoapods.org/?q=JTTarget).

```
[button addEventHandler:^(UIButton *sender, UIEvent *event) {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
} forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I like to handle this is to subclass `UIButton` and add a block-based action:

```
@interface BlockButton : UIButton

@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^onPress)();

@end

@implementation BlockButton

-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if(self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        [self addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(pressed:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) pressed:(id)sender
{
    if(self.onPress)self.onPress();
}

@end
```

Then instead of

```
[dismissButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)dismissThis
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

you can use:

```
dismissButton.onPress = ^{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
};
```

I'm sure you could adapt this slightly to use a `UIButton` category instead, if you really don't want a custom button class.

Answer (score 0):

I just created another method in an extension and called dismiss method there.

```
extension UIViewController {
  @objc func dismissAnimated() {
    dismiss(animated: true)
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
let viewController = WebviewController(url: url)
    viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
        title: "Cancel",
        style: .plain,
        target: viewController,
        action: #selector(dismissAnimated))
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
    let appearance = navController.navigationBar.standardAppearance
    appearance.backgroundColor = .white
    navController.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
    navController.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    return navController
```