# How can I set an action for a button without having to connect it to a method? iPhone

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

The only way i know how to run code for a button once it is pressed is to actually make a method for it using xCode. Is it possible to make an if statement asking if it was pressed instead? Something like

```
if(button.ispressed)
{
 //code here
}
```

EDIT: the if statement would be in a scheduled timer, so it would be constantly checked.

Comment: Sorry but you need to create a method to handle the control event. That's how it works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17607212/900873

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `:(id)sender`.

```
-(IBAction)someAction:(id)sender
{
     if(sender == yourButtonInstance)
     {
        //yourButtonInstance is Pressed.
     }
}
```

Comment: You can simply compare it `if(sender == button1)`.

Comment: @TheTiger so no need for `buttonispressed` do you mind editing if you sure it's simpler?

Answer (score 1):

No, because that goes against the [event-driven paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) (fancy talk for "you press a button, you get an action). To do what you ask, then you'd need to be constantly checking if any of the buttons on screen got pressed.

The closest thing you could achieve is something like, targetting all buttons to the same method, and then checking who was the caller.

For instance, let's link this three buttons (which have `@property` attached to them)

```
[self.button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(weAllGotPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(weAllGotPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.button3 addTarget:self action:@selector(weAllGotPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And then, in the callback method, do something like:

```
- (void)weAllGotPressed:(UIButton*)button
{
    if (button == self.button1)
    {
        // Do something
    }
    else if (button == self.button2)
    {
        // Do something else
    }
    else if (button == self.button3)
    {
        // Do another thing
    }
}
```

Can also use view tags to identify them, if you don't want to use @property to check the `UIButton` addresses.

Comment: I should of mentioned this, i did in one of the comments... I AM constantly checking though. The if statement would be part of a scheduled timer

Comment: And if you use `UISwitch` instead? Then you could easily check its state. Other than that, you would have to hack a UIButton to enable its selected state when tapping it and then check it from outside.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you should really only do this do for a control which does not intended to trigger an immediate action; for example you have have a number of checkboxes without handlers and an action button with a handler.

To determine the state of a control which maintains state; such as checkboxes and radio buttons; use the method `state` of `UIControl` or `NSControl`.

If a button does not remember state, such as most push buttons (they can be configured as push on/push off switches and hence maintain state) there is no way to determine whether a button was pushed without a handler to record the fact.

HTH