# Dismiss custom alert view iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm setting up a subclass of `UIView` to roll my own `UIAlertView` style view.  I've got everything set up properly with displaying the view, but I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to dismiss the view properly.  Specifically, when a user taps on the button in the view, it needs to animate out of the main view.  This is the code for the view itself:

```
+ (void)showCustomAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)titleString andMessage:(NSString *)messageString inView:(UIView *)view andButton1Title: (NSString *)button1Title andButton2Title: (NSString *)button2Title
{
UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject];

CGRect windowFrame = window.frame;

[view setAlpha:0.5f];

UIColor *buttonColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:130/255.0f blue:216/255.0f alpha:1];
UIColor *titleColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:153/255.0f blue:102/255.0f alpha:1];

// Shade
UILabel *shadeWindow = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, windowFrame.size.width, windowFrame.size.height)];
shadeWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
shadeWindow.alpha = 0.50f;

// Define size and origin of alert box
float alertBoxHeight = 225;
float alertBoxWidth = 200;
float alertBoxXorigin = windowFrame.size.width / 2 - (alertBoxWidth / 2);
float alertBoxYorigin = windowFrame.size.height / 2 - (alertBoxHeight / 2);

// Initialize background
UIView *alertBackground = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(alertBoxXorigin, alertBoxYorigin, alertBoxWidth, alertBoxHeight)];
alertBackground.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
[alertBackground.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
alertBackground.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

// Title Label
UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, alertBoxWidth, 40)];
titleLabel.text = titleString;
titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
titleLabel.textColor = titleColor;
titleLabel.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.05f].CGColor;
[titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Bold" size:20.0]];

// Title Divider
UILabel *titleDivider = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, alertBoxWidth, 1.0)];
titleDivider.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
titleDivider.alpha = 0.5f;

// Alert Message Text
UITextView *alertMessage = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, alertBoxWidth, alertBoxHeight - 90)];
alertMessage.text = messageString;
alertMessage.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
[alertMessage setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:15.0]];
alertMessage.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
alertMessage.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[alertMessage setEditable:NO];

// Button 1
UIButton *button1 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
UIButton *button2 = [[UIButton alloc] init];

[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

if (button2Title == nil)
{
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(10, alertBoxHeight - 50, alertBoxWidth - 20, 40);
}
else
{
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(10, alertBoxHeight - 50, (alertBoxWidth / 2) - 20, 40);
    button2.frame = CGRectMake(alertBoxWidth / 2 + 10, alertBoxHeight - 50, (alertBoxWidth / 2) - 20, 40);
}

button1.layer.backgroundColor = buttonColor.CGColor;
[button1 setTitle:button1Title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button1.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Bold" size:15.0f]];
button1.layer.cornerRadius = 2.5f;
[button1.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

// Button 2
button2.layer.backgroundColor = buttonColor.CGColor;
[button2 setTitle:button2Title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button2.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Bold" size:15.0f]];
button2.layer.cornerRadius = 2.5f;
[button2.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

// Bounce Implementation
alertBackground.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^
 {
     alertBackground.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
     // do something once the animation finishes, put it here
 }];

[window addSubview:view];
[window addSubview:alertBackground];

[view addSubview:shadeWindow];
[view bringSubviewToFront:alertBackground];

[alertBackground addSubview:button1];
[alertBackground addSubview:titleLabel];
[alertBackground addSubview:titleDivider];
[alertBackground addSubview:alertMessage];
[alertBackground addSubview:button2];
[alertBackground bringSubviewToFront:titleDivider];

 /*   [[[customAlerts sharedInstance] subViewArray] addObject:alertBackground];
[[[customAlerts sharedInstance] subViewArray] addObject:view];
[[[customAlerts sharedInstance] subViewArray] addObject:window];*/
}
```

When `button1` is tapped, for instance, I need to have it animate the view out of the `superView` and remove it from the stack.  I'm not sure how to handle this.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer here:

[Dismiss view controller from @selector without creating seperate method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606918/dismiss-view-controller-from-selector-without-creating-seperate-method)

Had to download some custom classes but it worked:

```
    [button1 addEventHandler:^(id sender, UIEvent *event)
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f animations:^{
        [alertBackground setAlpha:0.0f];
        [shadeWindow setAlpha:0.0f];
        [window setAlpha:0.0f];
    }];
} forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Custom classes can be found here:

https://github.com/ZeR0-Wu/JTTargetActionBlock

Answer (score 2):

To permanently remove a view, I generally use the `UIView` instance method `removeFromSuperview`. followed by a line setting the relevant variable to `nil`:

```
[myAlertView removeFromSuperview];
myAlertView = nil;
```

In your case then, I think you need to *move* the view off the screen by animating the its `bounds` property, then use the above couple of lines to remove any references to it.

Comment: If the view needs to dismiss from a button, is it possible to detect a tap on the button within the same function?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. When the button is tapped, your action method will receive the button as it's *sender* argument. Since the button's ``superview`` property will be the view you want to animate and dismiss you can grab a reference to it. Now, configure a ``UIView`` animation to do the moving bit, then, in the completion block remove the ``alertview`` from *it's* superview and set it to nil.

Comment: Can you give an example of what this would look like in code form? I'd be happy to submit this as the answer...